# Updating view during method execution

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I've been struggling with this for a while, here is the situation: I have a method that performs a really long operation that takes several minutes to execute, this method is triggered by a commandButton, so when the user clicks on it I want to start showing(in real time) some information to him about what the application is doing.

Here is what I've done so far:

managedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Mbean implements Serializable {

    public String message;

    public void startLongProcess(ActionEvent ev) {

        step1();
        message = "step 1 finished!";
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("msg");

        step2();
        message = "step 2 finished!";
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("msg");

        step3();
        message = "step 3 finished!";
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("msg");

    }
    ...
}
```

xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{mbean.startLongProcess}" ajax="true" />
<h:panelGroup id="msg">
    <h:outputText value="#{mbean.message}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

In this example I'm performing a 3 step operation that shows different a message after finishing each step, the problem is that the message is not being updated on the view during the method execution, the update only occurs after the whole process is finished.

Does anyone knows how to make it update in real time?

Comment: Have you tried primefaces push ?